# Color Animation of UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, uicolor

I would like to have a setup where a UILabel fill the width of the screen and is of color red. When a button is tapped I want the red label to move to the right off the screen while at the same time a UILabel of Color green comes in from the left of the screen.

The only way I can think of doing this is having two different UILabels and animating them to move off and on the screen.

Can I do this using just the one UILabel but fixed on the screen and just animated a Color change within that UILabel so it looks like the red has moved off screen to the right and the green has moved onscreen from the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to use two separate labels. Here is how you can do the animation:

You can put the green label on the screen in the same spot with the same constraints as the red label and then set it to be off-screen at first (Run this code in viewDidLoad):

```
playAgainButton.center = CGPointMake(playAgainButton.center.x - 500, playAgainButton.center.y)
```

It sounds to me like you want the red label to move from on screen to the left off of the screen and the green label to move from off-screen to the left on to the screen...Here is the animation:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.redLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.redLabel.center.x + 500, self.redLabel.center.y)

        self.greenLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.redLabel.center.x + 500, self.greenLabel.center.y)

    })
```

You can always mess with the animations to change the duration (I have it set to 0.5 seconds)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dan help on the animation would be great. I have code that generates the color for the background of the labels but not sure how to animate them. I'd need the animation to go from red to green moving off the right of the screen 10 times. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! I can send it to you in a couple of hours

Comment: @PeterGaffney I edited my answer! Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: If you're using AutoLayout (the default) then animating the position of your views directly doesn't work reliably. As soon as you do something that triggers an update to your layout, the views will snap back to their original position. Instead you need to hook up your constraints as outlets and animate changes to the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

That possible but your Green Label will only be visible after red has move out of the view since we are trying to use the same UILabel. You can do this using UIView animateWithDuration. You need to play with constraints with Frame. First you need to animate your Label from left to right till it moves of the screen and in completion block  reset its frame to extreme left and move it from left to right onto the screen.
Just check below animation which shows and hides a view:

https://github.com/quantumarun/BottomUp-Animation

Comment: Thanks thats spot on, combining your answer and dans answer is the job :)